# How to "lock" Location in Object Info for shading particles?

Tags: particles, shaders, shader-nodes

I made some particle simulations and want to add a pattern to the particles.
The only way I've found to project a texture properly onto the particles is via Location in Oject Info. The problem is, that of course when the particles move, the color changes. Is there a way to "lock" the pattern of the first frame for example, so that the particles stay the same color no matter where they are?

[image: Current node setup]

[image: How the particles are supposed to look throughout the simulation]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Object Info` node with `Mapping` and set `Location X, Y, Z` to be as Object's in the desired frame - this should help

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, since every ball renders as one icosphere, so every ball is the same color.